# How do I make this output prime numbers as factors instead of all factors?

Tags: java

I need this to output factors as prime numbers only.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number:");
    int theNum = keyboard.nextInt();

    int i;

    System.out.println("\nThe prime factors of " + theNum + " are:");
    for(i=1; i <= theNum/2; i++)

        if(theNum % i == 0)
    {

    System.out.print(i + " ");

    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Never use `.nextInt()`, since it will most likely cause issues for you later.  Always use `.nextLine()` and parse that into an `int`.

Comment: im new to programming can you type that line as a code out so i know what you mean?

Comment: @syb0rg You may want to include a reason - (something like) ... issues such as if you use `nextInt` and `nextLine` on the same `Scanner`, `nextInt` won't include the next end-of-line character, so you'll get an empty line on the next `nextLine` call.

Comment: @Dukeling I just don't see the reason to use `nextInt()` at all, when I could just use `nextLine` and parse all the information I need from that.

Comment: @user2230190 `String nextIntString = keyboard.nextLine();` (Gets the number as a single line)
`int nextInt = Integer.parseInt(nextIntString);` (Converts the string to an int)

Comment: the problem im having isnt the nextInt or anything like that its just i want the code to output prime factors instead of all factors

Comment: @syb0rg If the entire stream consists of only integers separated by white-space, why not use `nextInt`? It's much cleaner.

Comment: @Dukeling It helps with backwards compatibility if you need to change your code later on (like adding in `double`s). It's mostly a personal preference.

Comment: @user2230190 [The question Ted linked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570099/java-display-the-prime-factorization-of-a-number) seems to be close enough to answering this question.

Answer (score 0):

You basically just need to check for prime numbers

Some prime-number check function I copied from [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-determine-a-prime-number-in-java/):

```
boolean isPrime(int n) {
    //check if n is a multiple of 2
    if (n%2==0) return false;
    //if not, then just check the odds
    for(int i=3;i*i<=n;i+=2) {
        if(n%i==0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then just add the `isPrime(i)` check:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number:");
    int theNum = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.println("\nThe prime factors of " + theNum + " are:");

    for(int i = 1; i <= theNum / 2; i++)
      if (theNum % i == 0 && isPrime(i))
        System.out.print(i + " ");
}
```

[Test](http://ideone.com/tnqrDS).