# Prime Factorization Program Java

Tags: java, math, primes, prime-factoring

These are the instruction I have for the program:

Write a program that asks the user for an integer (using JOptionPane) and then prints out  its prime factorization.

For example, when the user enters 150, the program should print  "Prime factorization of 150:  2  3  5  5".

Use a class FactorGenerator with methods nextFactor and hasMoreFactors (a predicate method).  The instance fields should be number and factor.  The hasMoreFactors method should initialize factor to 2 and use a while loop to increment factor until factor divides into number evenly (in which case hasMoreFactors returns a value of true) or factor becomes too large (in which case hasMoreFactors returns a value of false).

In FactorGeneratorTest, the user should be allowed to enter as many integers as he/she desires.  Input should continue until the cancel button is pressed.  It is suggested that the integers you enter are 30, 100, 2310, and 27225.

Here is my FactorGenerator class so far:

```
package primeFactorization;

public class FactorGenerator {

public FactorGenerator(double input) {
    number = input;
}

public String hasMoreFactors() {
    factor = 2;
    boolean loop = true;
    primeFactors = "Prime Factors are: ";
    while(loop) {
        if(number % factor == 0) {
            number = number / factor;
            primeFactors = (number + ", ");
            }
            if(factor > number) {
                loop = false;
            }
            if(number % factor != 0) {
                factor++;
            }
            if(number < 2) {
                loop = false;
            }
        }
        return primeFactors;
    }

    private String primeFactors;
    private boolean hasFactor;
    private double number;
    private double factor;
}
```

And here is my test class:

```
package primeFactorization;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class FactorGeneratorTest 
    {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number. ");
        Double num = Double.parseDouble(input);

        FactorGenerator factors = new FactorGenerator(num);

    System.out.println(factors.hasMoreFactors());
}
}
```

How do I go about making this work?

Comment: Posibly duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570099/java-display-the-prime-factorization-of-a-number

Comment: what exactly does NOT work so far ?

Comment: How large of a number are you allowing? Specifically, how large will the prime factors be? You can factorize all numbers under 10^6 or so and store the results in a fairly small amount of time. Larger numbers require factorizing them individually and can require specialized algorithms to solve in a reasonable amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

You are reassigning the String variable primeFactors in hasMoreFactors() method with intermediate values of the variable number. primeFactors should be concatenated with values of prime factor (i.e values of variable factor). The hasMoreFactors() should be like below :

```
public String hasMoreFactors() {
        factor = 2;
        boolean loop = true;
        primeFactors = "Prime Factors are: ";
        while (loop) {
            if (number % factor == 0) {
                number = number / factor;
                primeFactors += (factor + ", ");
            }
            if (factor > number) {
                loop = false;
            }
            if (number % factor != 0) {
                factor++;
            }
            if (number < 2) {
                loop = false;
            }
        }
        return primeFactors;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:
input is 35, you start with factor 2 but `35 % 2 = 1` so you never come to `factor++`.
Put this direct to the end of the loop and ask if there was a no factor found in the round.