# Division By Primes in Java

Tags: java, primes, division

I am just wondering if there is a pre-made method for division by primes? I can't find one, but my math teacher had two years of programming in college and said there is one. So is there a pre-made method for me to put an input and get an output of the multiples for the primes of the number, or do I have to make it myself?

Comment: Not sure that there is a native method but I think this might help.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAlgorithmsPrimeFactorization/article.html

Comment: I think your teacher's off their rocker; in my 7+ years of working with Java (collegiate and professional), I've never known anything like that to exist in the *core* library.  Are you looking for "prime factorization" though?  From your title it's very confusing, but your description leads me to believe you're looking for prime factorization.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  But 1) BigInteger has methods for dividing by an integer,  2) there is no builtin method for *factorizing* a number ... which is what I think you are really asking, and 3) asking us to find 3rd party libraries for you is OFF-TOPIC.

Comment: @feltersnach I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no pre-made method for division by primes in Java. You will have to create one yourself and you should as you will learn a few important concepts.

Comment: He wants to factorize a number to primes.

Comment: If there's not a pre-made, I think I'll just make one.

Comment: @wampycakes that link I posted has a method for prime factorization.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear enough, but as your last words indicates, you want a core Java library function that factorizes numbers into its [prime factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_factor). There is no such thing in Core Java library, as far as I know. Not every possible method can be included in core library.

Look at these two solutions:

- [**Program: Calculating Prime Factors**](http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_java/numbers.html#AEN127)
- [**Faster prime factorization for huge BigIntegers in Java**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570099/java-display-the-prime-factorization-of-a-number)

Note that these methods use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), so that they are arbitrary precision numbers.

If you want a simple API, you can use [Primes](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/primes/Primes.html) class from Apache Common Java componnets. The method [primeFactors](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/primes/Primes.html#primeFactors%28int%29) does the job:

```
public static List<Integer> primeFactors(int n)

Prime factors decomposition

Parameters:
    n - number to factorize: must be ≥ 2
Returns:
    list of prime factors of n
Throws:
    MathIllegalArgumentException - if n < 2.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new and don't know such method or smth, but u can easily make it urself. I try and get something like u can see below. 
Don't be hard on it.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class arrayString {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a=1024; //this is number
    int b = a;  //this is number
    int mult = 1;
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i =2; i<=a; i++){
        while (a%i == 0)
        {
            a /= i;
            list.add(i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(b+" factorization is:");
    for (Integer data:list){
        System.out.println(data);
        mult *= data;

    }
    //check
    System.out.println(mult);

}
}
```